# Prevent enterprise iOS app from being removed

Tags: ios, mdm, ios-enterprise

I'd like to prevent an enterprise iOS app from being removed by users. Apple provides documentation on [how to do this for Web Clips](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/ConfigurationProfileExamples/ConfigurationProfileExamples.html), but I'm struggling to find anything related to actual apps. Is it possible? and if so then how to do it?

The ideal solution would involve a setting in the plist installation file, but options involving configuration profiles or an MDM would also work.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know to prevent apps from being deleted is as follows:

On your iPhone/iPad go to Settings -> General -> Restrictions -> Deleting Apps (off).

You will have to enter a Restrictions Password and turn Restrictions on.

Comment: I do believe he was looking for a way to do this programmatically and still allow users to delete other apps, though.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it's impossible to prevent deletion of particular apps using public API and MDM.

Actually, I haven't seen solution for this even for private API's.

P.S. sangony is right. Prevetion to delete all apps are the closest you can get. And it's configurable through MDM.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a lot of time on this plist thing but i couldn't find any thing.I assume it's not possible through simple plist setting.

As far as i know 
for any non jailbroken device is concerned

You can make apps undeletable by making following selections in iOS.

***Settings -> General -> Restrictions -> Deleting Apps -> Off***

[image: settings]

**In case of enterprise apps:**

You may try creating a custom configuration profile using iPCU(iPhone Configuration utility) or Apple Configurator and install it on multiple devices or you can use enterprise MDM to do this.

**FYI:**

This feature was introduced in apple **iOS 4.3**

Comment: This answer was already given, and isn't really what was being asked anyway.

Comment: Hi Andrew I have edited the answer to make it more relevant.I have said my conclusion about the question and How to achieve this in alternative ways using pictures so that anybody can know easily and and I have mentioned of mdm and other mac utilities.Kindly go through it.